# Convert comma separated numbers in a character string to numeric vector

Tags: r

I am struggling to convert comma separated numbers in a string to numeric vector. (using R)
Example:

```
x <- "1, 2, 3"
as.numeric(x)

#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
>       #NAs introduced by coercion

So: any suggestions?

Comment: You cant have a numeric string. You can have a numeric vector, i.e. `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ', ')))`

Comment: Or use `scan` to "read in" the string and convert it to a numeric vector as you would use `read.csv` or similar functions: like `scan(textConnection(x), sep=",")`.

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot:-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure that it's not the best way to do it, but it works :

```
as.numeric(strsplit(x,split=", ",fixed=TRUE)[[1]])
    [1] 1 2 3
```

I hope it helps